# scikit image (skimage) exclude white background in gradient computation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image, opencv, python

I am using skimage to compute gradients of an image and eventually do some segmentation. The image is primarily of the same color with some abnormalities (segments of interest) and the background is white. I want to exclude the white background in the the gradient computation. The color difference between the main image and the white background is being picked up by the gradient. How could I exclude that in gradient computation and restrict it to just the main image ?

The following lines of code are used for gradient computation

```
from skimage import filters

image_denoised = filters.rank.median(image_gray, disk(2))
gradient = filters.rank.gradient(image_denoised, disk(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a mask region in skimages gradient function, see [skimage.filters.rank.gradient](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.gradient).

Values > 0 in the mask will be included in the gradient calculation, so as you already have your background as intensity 0 you can basically use your image as the mask:

```
from skimage import filters

image_denoised = filters.rank.median(image_gray, disk(2))
gradient = filters.rank.gradient(image_denoised, disk(5), mask=image_denoised)
```